# Constant updating of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

I have trouble trying to click on a JButton and constantly updating the Conway's Game of Life. So what I have is firstly to give the rules from the Game of Life and simulate and calculate the position for the counters. Then update the frame by setting the background colour to the JButton, and then delay and repeat. But the problem is when I press the start button, it gets stuck due to the fact I was trying to use `while` loop.

There is a separate package called the AI_Processor which is just the simulation and calculation which is all done correctly, just the updating got some problems.

Code Parts:

```
public void updateFrame() {
  AI.AI_Movement_Update();
  addColour();
}

public void addColour() {
  for (int i = 0; i < fieldHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fieldWidth; j++) {
      if (AI.getPosB(j, i) == true) {
        testMolecules[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
      } else {
        testMolecules[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
      }

    }
  }
}
Timer tm = new Timer(1000,this);


if (ae.getSource() == start) {
  while(true) {
    updateFrame();
    tm.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Those are part codes that means if you see something is missing but appears to be there like the ae.getSource that means i have already implement actionlistener juz cause its too long...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minial Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 4):

You state:

> But the problem is when I press the start button, it got stucked due to the fact i was trying to use while loop.

Then get rid of the `while (true)` loop since all this does is tie up the Swing event thread rendering your GUI useless. You have a Swing Timer, and you could call the model's update method in the timer's ActionListener so that it is called with each tick of the timer, and then you would not need the while loop. Other options include keeping the `while (true)` loop, but calling it in a background thread, but if you do this, take care to update your GUI on the Swing event thread only.

> ...Sorry for the formatting though...

I have formatted your code for you, but for future reference you will want to read the help section of this site regarding how to format questions and containing code. Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

---

Other random thoughts:

- Regarding `Timer tm = new Timer(1000,this);`, I try to avoid having my GUI classes implement listener interfaces as it forces the class to do too much, breaking the Single Responsibility Principle. Better to use either a separate listener class, a Control class that assigns listeners, or an anonymous inner class.
- For more information on Swing threading issues, please see [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

---

For more on anonymous inner classes, again, get rid of the `while (true)` bit and instead try something like:

```
// note that TIMER_DELAY is a constant, and needs to be smaller than 1000, perhaps 20?
Timer tm = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     updateFrame();
  }
});
// the start call below can only be called inside of a method or a constructor
tm.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
sorry, previous solution was bad :-(
EDIT:
you could use anonymous inner class for this

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html
see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

If you use Timer, then you should pass an instance of ActionListener
Timer creates a new Thread, so while is not neccessary...

Not tested:

```
public void updateFrame(){
  AI.AI_Movement_Update();
  addColour();
}

public void addColour() {
  for (int i = 0; i < fieldHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fieldWidth; j++) {
      if (AI.getPosB(j, i) == true) {
        testMolecules[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
      } else {
        testMolecules[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
      }

    }
  }
}
if(ae.getSource() == start)
    new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
        updateFrame();
    }).start();
```

Comment: Welcome back to Java! :)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't update constantly but it only updates per click

Comment: @NicholasChoo I have to see your JButton listener code to help you, sorry

Comment: @NicholasChoo: post your code here for **all** to see please, not in pastebin.

Comment: @NicholasChoo: and to solve your issue of "only updates per click" -- use an anonymous inner ActionListener class for your Timer as I suggested in my answer. Keep your listeners separate. For example, please see the edit to my answer.